# Severe injury of a space station astronaut

Tags: biology, space-travel, medical

Let's suppose that an astronaut on a space station is severely injured while doing plumbing work outside: a malfunction of the MMU (like in the movie "Geostorm") causes him to tumble uncontrollably, crashing into a truss and breaking his leg femurs. He is brought into the space station and helped out of the space suit while writihing in pain. The station's doctor gives him a sedative and examines him. Even without x-ray equipment, he understands that the injured astronaut can not return to earth normally. There is no equipment for performing fracture surgeries on the station and the most the doctor is trained for doing in microgravity is stitching wounds and treating decompression injuries; this is the first documented case of a bone injury in space.

My question is:

**How can an astronaut with major bone fractures be stabilized and treated, and if possible, safely brought to earth for surgery? Can a rescue mission be arranged to bring the tools and/or a professional surgeon to the station in order to help the doctor and his patient?**

Comment: Might want to change it from ‘how can the astronaut’ to ‘how can an astronaut’ to make it more worldbuildy and less plot-specific

Comment: If you already defined what is and what is not on this station, where is world building element of this question?

Comment: Changing a single preposition does not magically remove the plot-specific nature of this question. This question, to its core, is not about worldbuilding at all.

Comment: Go ask on Space SE. I'm sure there is a protocol for rescuing astronauts with broken bones or who are otherwise incapacitated. (as it is now, it wouldn't be a good question on Space SE either, but it could be rephrased to be, I think)

Comment: @Azuaron: the idea was more changing from a question about a single specific incident (plot related) to general protocols (world related). As it stands this question is on the border of not worldbuilding because there’s nothing here that isn’t already covered by the real world, but there is nothing wrong with couching a plot specific question in more generalised terms. The difference between ‘my astronaut’ and ‘all astronauts in my world’ is a very big difference.

Comment: How can someone who can only "stitch wounds and treat decompression injuries" be called a *doctor*? Every Army medic I know can do much, much more than that. Anyone can set and splint a non-compound fracture away from a joint. You have not told us if it's a compound fracture or not (please edit your question), but we must assume you mean it's a compound fracture because the astronaut requires surgery. That's a problem too: Any blow hard enough to cause a compound fracture through the layers of a space suit is also likely to kill the astronaut by catastrophically compromising the space suit.

Comment: You are asking a lot of questions at once. None of which are about building a fictional world.

Answer (score 2):

He would most likely die.

Astronauts are very intelligent, educated people. Some of them are, in fact, doctors, but very few of them have been surgeons. So right off the bat, you have a lack of expertise among the crew.

Now, of course, a surgeon could "get on the phone" with them, but you can only do so much without being there in person, especially when discussing a complicated procedure such as this one.

But there are further complications to consider. I don't think we've actually developed any surgery procedures for zero gravity. Fluids will be going in weird directions, obstructing the view of the surgeon, etc.

Second, the bones and tissue will likely heal in rather unexpected ways in zero g.

All in all, this is likely going to lead to deadly complications which you can't get around in the time window it would take to save this person's life.

Answer (score 2):

## The setting can be tailored to fit

This is a classic case of things being as dire as you need them to be. The astronaut's survival depends on two things: the injury, and the things needed to rescue them.

### The injury

If you wish to tailor the scenario so that the astronaut cannot make the journey down to Earth again, what you need to achieve is that they cannot suffer acceleration, either sustained acceleration and/or shaking. Usually **injuries to the central nervous system**, that is to say brain and or spine, are typically such injuries.

If you wish to make the injury less severe so that some special equipment — like a [vacuum splint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_splint) — can be brought with a [resupply mission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commercial_Resupply_Services), then you can do that as well.

Which brings us to...

### The rescue

As both real life cases ([Apollo 13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_13)) and fictional ones (for instance [The Martian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Martian_(Weir_novel))) show, all scenarios where the space agency throws everything they have at the problem are credible. The reason for this is that 1) the agency cannot hide the accident; it **will** be public knowledge very soon and 2) an emergency like this strikes even higher than the [Missing White Woman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_white_woman_syndrome) or Kids/Puppies In Distress syndrome. "Everyone" will be up in arms over this and want to see a good outcome. There is no way the space agency will be caught having to answer "Why did you not do everything in your power to save the astronaut?" with "We felt it was not worth the effort/cost".

So is it credible that a [space station expedition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_International_Space_Station_expeditions) will be scrubbed in order to make room for a surgeon? Yes, this does not even need any extensive exposition to motivate this to the reader. And as I said above: anything that fits in a resupply mission can be sent up. As was the case in **The Martian**, this may even be a major plot point.

However both of these things require that a mission is **imminent** when the accident happens, that is to say the mission was already scheduled to be sent up within — or close enough to be rushed into — the time-frame we are talking about. There is no stockpile of rockets tucked away that can be used for such missions willy-nilly.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that the best option would be to return him to earth as quickly as possible. A lot would depend on the exact situation such as the availability of space craft and launch time table etc. One option would be for him to return immediately on the craft that he arrived on.

Although they can’t treat his leg properly they would have plenty of materials on the space station. The engineers would be able to find all sorts of things to jury rig a half decent brace and with  some expert medical communications from ground control the injured astronaut could probably be stabilized an sedated enough to return to earth, even if the situation was far from ideal.

Another possibility again depending on the circumstances would be to send a relief crew perhaps including a doctor or at the very least a well-made supportive leg brace for him to use plus appropriate medication.